# How to get the default MySql values in `firstOrNew` in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

If I use `firstOrCreate` then the default values are given for the model that I set up in the database. But when I use `firstOrNew` the values are not given and are instead given out as `NULL`. Is there any way to fix this aside from using `firstOrCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `firstOrNew` will just create a new instance of your model when it doesn't get a result from the database. Therefore it does not get the default values from the database.

So I guess you have at least two options here. The first one would be the one you already mentioned using `firstOrCreate` (this is not something I would recommend because this could lead to incorrect state in your database). Another option would be to add 'Accessors`on your model with which will return either the value retrieved from the database or when it's`null` it will return the default value you define.

```php
public function getMyFieldAttribute($myField)
{
    if ($myField === null) {
        return 'my-default-value';
    }

    return $myField;
}
```

More info on accessors can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks. :D